# Prove that the set N of normal numbers has negligible complement.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm taking a graduate course called Real Variables I, without having taken the prerequisite of Real Analysis II, and having taken only Real Analysis I. Therefore, I'm brand new to measure theory and am trying to understand some basic proofs.

For example, I know the following:

A subset $A$ of $Ω$ is said to be negligible if for any $ϵ>0$ there exists a finite or countable collection ${I_k}$ of intervals, satisfying $A⊆\bigcup_{k}I_k$ and $\sum_k l(I_k)<ϵ$, where $l(I_k)$ is the length of the interval $I_k$.

The set $N$ of normal numbers is defined as N = ${\{w\in Ω: \lim_{n\to ∞} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n d_i(w) = \frac{1}{2}}\}$.

Now, how do I show that the set N of normal numbers has negligible complement?

Comment: $$\text{the word set}\in\text{the question}\ \ \not\!\!\!\implies\text{the question}\in\text{set theory tags}$$

Comment: I assume $d_i(w)$ is the $i$th binary digit of $w$. But what is $\Omega$?

Comment: Sorry, Ω = (0,1].

Comment: There is an elementary (though far from trivial) proof in [this PDF](http://www.emis.de/journals/AUSM/C2-1/math21-8.pdf) that almost every real number is normal in all bases $b\ge 2$. A proof of the binary case, which is what you want, that uses no measure theory can be found [here](http://works.bepress.com/rnillsen/3/).

Comment: Great reference Brian